# Вопросы по C#.NET

Tags: c#

Пожалуйста, ответьте на вопросы:

1. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на `Button1`, запускался, например, проводник и открывал `C:\Program Files`?
2. Как можно сделать так, чтобы картинка (`PictureBox1`), появлялась в разных местах, и через определенное кол-во времени.

Answer (score 3):

Запуск проводника:

```
...
string PathToMyFolder = "C:\\MyFolder";
Process.Start(PathToMyFolder);
...
```

на счёт картинки и `PictureBox` по-подробнее можно?

**UPDATE:**

```
    private int x;
    private int Y;
    ...
    //Переотрисовка формы:
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Image santa = Image.FromFile("Santa.jpg");//Ваше изображение

        Random rand = new Random();

        //по этим координатам зарисуете изображение, чтобы оно исчезло
        x = rand.Next(0,Form1.Width);
        y = rand.Next(0,Form1.Hight);

        Point location = new Point(x, y);//Рандомное место положение изображения

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(santa, location);
    }
    ...
    //Собственно таймер, System.Windows.Forms.Timer, перетащите на форму, установите  myTimer.Interval = 30000, запустите myTimer.Start(), а потом обработайте событие Tick:
   private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                            EventArgs myEventArgs) {
    Refresh();//Вызывает OnPaint
    }
    ...
```

Хотите узнать больше:

- [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)
- [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, а на счет картинки смотрите, смотрите у меня есть рожица Санты, и хочется чтобы она 1 раз в 30 секунд появлялась в любом месте формы, потом опять исчезала и потом появлялась уже В ДРУГОМ МЕСТЕ, и так до бесконечности.

Comment: Image santa = Image.FromFile("Santa.jpg");//Ваше изображение

 Зачем загружать картинку при каждой перерисовке? Можно было это сделать при создании формы.

Comment: ага, и создавать объекты ``Random`` и ``Point`` - просто для наглядности!